# Why does my Verilog Waveform Suddenly Stop When a Value Changes to 1

Tags: verilog, infinite-loop, pipeline, microprocessors

I am creating a pipelined processor with a hazard unit. During the simulation, when Flush = 1, the program waveform halts. I believe there is some sort of infinite loop in my code and this hazard unit does not return any value. In the image, I attached you can see in the value column that Flush becomes 1. But in the module it is called from it is still zero, so it is likely that it loops at this point.

[Image of Waveform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFGwe.png)

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module Hazard_Unit(input BranchD, MtoRFSelE, MtoRFSelM, RFWEE, RFWEM, RFWEW, RST, input [4:0] RsD, RtD, RsE, RtE, RFAE, RFAM, RFAW,
                   output reg Stall, ForwardAD, ForwardBD, Flush, output reg [1:0] ForwardAE, ForwardBE);

reg LWStall, BRStall;

always @(*) begin
    if (RST) begin
        ForwardAD = 1'b0;
        ForwardBD = 1'b0;
        ForwardAE = 2'b00;
        ForwardBE = 2'b00;
        LWStall = 1'b0;
        BRStall = 1'b0;
        Stall = 1'b0;
        Flush = 1'b0;
    end

    else begin
        if ((RsE != 0) && RFWEM && (RsE == RFAM)) ForwardAE = 2'b10;
        else if ((RsE != 0) && RFWEW && (RsE == RFAW)) ForwardAE = 2'b01;
        else ForwardAE = 2'b00;

        if ((RtE != 0) && RFWEM && (RtE == RFAM)) ForwardBE = 2'b10;
        else if ((RtE != 0) && RFWEW && (RtE == RFAW)) ForwardBE = 2'b01;
        else ForwardBE = 2'b00;

        if (MtoRFSelE && ((RtE == RsD) || (RtE == RtD))) LWStall = 1'b1;
        else LWStall = 1'b0;

        if ((RsD != 0) && (RsD == RFAM) && RFWEM) ForwardAD = 1'b1;
        else ForwardAD = 1'b0;

        if ((RtD != 0) && (RtD == RFAM) && RFWEM) ForwardBD = 1'b1;
        else ForwardBD = 1'b0;

        if ((RsD == RFAE || RtD == RFAE) && BranchD && RFWEE || (RsD == RFAM || RtD == RFAM) && BranchD && MtoRFSelM) BRStall = 1'b1;
        else BRStall = 1'b0;

        if (LWStall || BRStall) begin
            Flush = 1'b1;
            Stall = 1'b0;
        end
        else begin
            Flush = 1'b0;
            Stall = 1'b1;
        end
    end
end
endmodule
```

Comment: most likely it is your test bench which stops simulation as flush becomes 1. You have not provided its code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed it is likely that you have a combinatorial loop.

I could search where it is, but I prefer to give you a general method to solve these issues. This one I use if it happens to me (once in a blue moon :-)

1. Make sure you use a clock which is long enough. e.g. 100 or 500 time units. This is in general a good practice. A clock time of 1 high and 1 low is a disaster in the making. Your simulation will not run any slower because of this
2. Put a `#5` between statements.

   ```
   if ((RsE != 0) && RFWEM && (RsE == RFAM)) ForwardAE = 2'b10;
   else if ((RsE != 0) && RFWEW && (RsE == RFAW)) ForwardAE = 2'b01;
   else ForwardAE = 2'b00;
   #5;

   if ((RtE != 0) && RFWEM && (RtE == RFAM)) ForwardBE = 2'b10;
   else if ((RtE != 0) && RFWEW && (RtE == RFAW)) ForwardBE = 2'b01;
   else ForwardBE = 2'b00;
   #5;
   ...
   ```

Now your waveform is likely to keep running and show you where the oscillation is. Don't forget to remove the #5 again once you have fixed the code.

Next point:
Your code is generally wrong. You are producing lots of latches in that `if` statement. Every one of your variables `ForwardAD, ForwardBD, ForwardAE ...` must be assigned a value in each `if` statement. Or you should start with giving them a default value right after the `else`:

```
else begin
    ForwardAD = ..;
    ForwardBD = ..;
    ForwardAE = .;
    ...
    if ((RsE != 0) &....
```

If you can't do that, probably the whole section should be a clocked statement:

```
always @(posedge some_clock) begin
```